# Admob Native Advanced -> Smart banner compatible template

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob, native-ads

I have read about those templates at : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates like Google recommends [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates) to use them, but there are only two options which are too big comparing with normal `banners or smart banners`.

Just wonder if someone can help providing a tested template to `automatically fit it's height` based on device screen resolution like normal smart banners ?

Below you can see a template that i use sometimes, but it is still little large (to works OK it needs height min `90dp`.

So, if someone can help with another template it would be awesome, it needs to be compatible with `32dp, 50dp, 90dp` height and to automatically choose what height to use based on devices screen resolutions

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/native_ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_notification_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gnt_rounded_corners_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ad_text"
            android:textColor="@color/gnt_ad_green"
            android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/primary"
                        android:text="Ads primary text by adversitier"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#0000FF"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/secondary"
                            android:text="Adverstitier"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="bottom"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:isIndicator="true"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:stepSize="0.5" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/cta"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@color/gnt_blue"
                            android:textColor="@color/gnt_white"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

Comment: Don't use a fixed dp size if you want to support all types of screens instead use sdp 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: @Mr.Patel, SDP cannot be used for current case